# Android SDK keep NFC on

Tags: android, nfc

I am using the NFC capability of an android phone to induce a small amount of current in a coil to charge up a capacitor. currently i am using the NFC-V application in the app store ([source code available here](http://www2.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/st25-nfc-rfid-software/stsw-m24lr012.html)) to achieve this. What I found is the phone can charge up the capacitor easily when i constantly remove the board and place it near the field again, but if i leave the board sationaly in the field it only successfully charges about 30% of the time (maintains 3.3V when sucessful).

I believe this could be due to something in android API which turns off the magnetic field once a tag is discovered?

Could someone explain what the NFC API does once it discovers a tag (i.e does it turn off the magnetic feild once detected and turn it back on when removed?)

further more is there a way to keep the magnetic field constantly on using the NFC api?

Comment: Is this only a coil or is there an actual NFC(-compatible) tag attached to the coil that gets detect by Android?

Comment: there is an NFC compatible tag attached to the coil. further more there is an external low power micro controller which is run by any excess power in the coil.the circuit was designed based on this discovery board: http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/f8/f5/c2/20/b5/55/42/26/DM00068980.pdf/files/DM00068980.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00068980.pdf

Comment: @MichaelRoland your response to my earlier question actually solved this issue

Comment: If that's the case and the problem no longer exists (or the other rather similar question solve the problem), you might then want to close/delete this one.